# Convert RGB values to 8 bit digit

Tags: python, numpy

I have a coloured image img. I want to create a new NumPy array based on the RGB value of the image. I can do a loop and convert the new array value based on the RGB values: say, newVal = convertToBinary(R) + "-" + convertToBinary(G) + "-" +  convertToBinary(B). The newVal will then be appended to a NumPy array variable BinaryVal.  The convertToBinary is a function that converts the number to a binary representation.

Say I have this

```
import numpy as np
img = np.array([[[1 2 3] [0 0 1] [ 1 1 1]] [[0 0 0] [1 1 1] [ 0 0 0]]])
```

Its a 3 x 2 image. The results should be 6 arrays containing binary values:

1st array is = `00000001-00000010-00000011`

2nd array is = `00000000-00000000-00000001`

3rd array is = `00000001-00000001-00000001`

and so on.

I know that there is a way to do this in a NumPysh way. But I just don't know-how.

Comment: We have no idea what shape/type your image data is, so it won't be possible to provide a solution. Please edit your code block to be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in Python

Comment: The image is a NumPy array of shape (n,m,3)

Answer (score 0):

To get the pixel values in the exact format you're looking for, use the builtin `format` method:

```
>>> BinaryVal = []
>>> for row in img:
...     for pixel in row:
...             BinaryVal.append(format(pixel[0],'08b')+"-"+format(pixel[1],'08b')+"-"+format(pixel[2],'08b'))
... 
>>> BinaryVal
['00000001-00000010-00000011', '00000000-00000000-00000001', '00000001-00000001-00000001', '00000000-00000000-00000000', '00000001-00000001-00000001', '00000000-00000000-00000000']
```

There isn't a numpy formatting method that actually changes the way the numbers are stored, but if you're only interested in how they're displayed you could use [np.set_printoptions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html)

```
>>> np.set_printoptions(formatter={'int_kind':"{:08b}".format})
>>> img
array([[[00000001, 00000010, 00000011],
        [00000000, 00000000, 00000001],
        [00000001, 00000001, 00000001]],

       [[00000000, 00000000, 00000000],
        [00000001, 00000001, 00000001],
        [00000000, 00000000, 00000000]]])
```